# Listening to HTML check boxes in jTextPane (or an alternative)?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I am using non-editable JTextPane to show some data in HTML format. I have set contentType to "text/html" and it works. Now I wanted to add HTML checkboxes in JTextPane, and listen to their change, and be able to retrieve if a specific checkBox is selected. Is this possible?

The text of JTextPane is in this format:

```
<html><form>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="value" /> checkbox1<br />
</form></html>
```

Should I be using JTextPane for this purpose at all, or is there a better control? Regular check boxes are not an option, because I need a HTML format for styling it easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally you would use a JEditorPane to display HTML.

Depending on your requirement there are two ways to go about this:

1. Swing components are actually added to the editor pane. So once the docuemnt has been parsed and the editor pane has been revalidated() you should be able to just get a list of all the components added to the editor pane. You can check the class name to find the components you want.
2. The HTMLDocument contains attributes about each component added including the components model. So you can search the document to get the model for every checkbox.

Here is some general code to get your started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

public class GetComponent extends JFrame
{
    public GetComponent()
        throws Exception
    {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("form.html");

        JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
        editor.setContentType( "text/html" );
        editor.setEditable( false );
        editor.read(reader, null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( editor );
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(400, 300) );
        add( scrollPane );

        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        setVisible(true);

        //  display the attributes of the document

        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)editor.getDocument();
        ElementIterator it = new ElementIterator(doc);
        Element element;

        while ( (element = it.next()) != null )
        {
            System.out.println();

            AttributeSet as = element.getAttributes();
            Enumeration enumm = as.getAttributeNames();

            while( enumm.hasMoreElements() )
            {
                Object name = enumm.nextElement();
                Object value = as.getAttribute( name );
                System.out.println( "\t" + name + " : " + value );

                if (value instanceof DefaultComboBoxModel)
                {
                    DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel)value;

                    for (int j = 0; j < model.getSize(); j++)
                    {
                        Object o = model.getElementAt(j);
                        Object selected = model.getSelectedItem();
                        System.out.print("\t\t");

                        if ( o.equals( selected ) )
                            System.out.println( o + " : selected" );
                        else
                            System.out.println( o );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //  display the components added to the editor pane

        for (Component c: editor.getComponents())
        {
            Container parent = (Container)c;
            System.out.println(parent.getComponent(0).getClass());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    GetComponent frame = new GetComponent();
                }
                catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could handle javascript events in JTextPane, so I don't think toggling the checkbox is an option.